# How to hide circle from radio button and only show icon in qt?

Tags: css, qt

I want user to select a theme which he wants to apply to the document.
So i have created a popup dialog which has multiple themes which are qradiobutton. But I want to display only icons and remove circle from the widget.

I have tried visible:hidden for the radio button but that didn't worked.

Comment: It will be nice if you provide some code as a fiddle , It will help us to solve your query

Answer (score 3):

If you want to customize `QRadioButton` with style-sheets I suggest you check the reference documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qradiobutton-widget

You should also find useful the examples given in Qt documentation as it shows how to replace the check indicator by different images:

```
QRadioButton::indicator {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
}

QRadioButton::indicator::unchecked {
    image: url(:/images/radiobutton_unchecked.png);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:hover {
    image: url(:/images/radiobutton_unchecked_hover.png);
}
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qradiobutton

If you do this yo can just use the indicator to display the icon and leave the `QRadioButton` label empty.

However, I have to warn you, depending on which QStyle you are using, it could happen that using style-sheets destroys completely the style of a component. A general example is: you are using a style where buttons have round corners, you use style-sheets to change the font of the button and as a result the button does not have round corners anymore. This is caused by incompatibilities between some QStyle and the style-sheet mechanism. If you do not want to make a multi platform app, it might not be an issue as you will use only one style, but if you make an multi platform app, you have to check every possible style you platform can have on the different platforms.

So if you want to have a `QRadioButton` without indicator and not use style-sheets, you can do it in C++ directly by subclassing `QAbstractButton`. Just make sure you set your class to be `autoExclusive` so that is will behave like a radio button.

Answer (score 0):

would you try this? ( visible => visibility )

```
input[type="radio"] {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

or

```
input[type="radio"] {
   display: none;
}
```